# Does anyone know what the file ~/Library/Preferences/com.npvdata.client is for?

Tags: security, file

I had a heck of a time with the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.npvdata.client`.  Looked like it was some kind of cryptographic key file, and when I went to edit it, not only could I not change it, but also while I was editing it the file `com.npvdata.client.swp` and `com.npvdata.client~` showed up, even though I was editing it in `vi` which doesn't create backup files.  I had a really hard time deleting it, too.

I'm guessing this is part of some kind of copy protection or licensing scheme, but I'd like to know for sure where it is from, what it is for, and what danger there is, if any, of someone else getting a hold of it.

Comment: `vi` is responsible of creating `.com.npvdata.client.swp`.

Comment: This file is marked with the 'uchg' (user immutable) flag, which is why it was hard to delete (or edit).  You can use the chflags(1) command to clear the flag for editing it (and to put it back on afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my Googling-fu is stronger than yours, this appears to be linked to the [Viscosity VPN client](http://www.sparklabs.com/viscosity/).

According to Viscosity technical support, Viscosity stores registration and trial information in this file, however it can be safely deleted if needed.

Comment: Also, the file is most likely in the binary property list format. Xcode and the command-line `defaults` tool can typically read and write these files.

Comment: `plutil -convert xml1` will convert this property list in an `XML` version 1. This format can be edited directly with `vi` without too many hidden side effects.